# What configuration do we need to for Rails 6.0.2 App to deploy in AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, passenger, ruby-on-rails-6

I have an AWS EC2 instance, where I have deployed my rails application.

RAILS - 6.0.2, Ruby - 2.6.6 & Apache2 + Passenger

I have configured Apache2 & Passenger with the root folder till rails_app/public.

I am still getting this error:

```
AH01797: client denied by server configuration
```

Configuration of apache file in sites-available:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@default/gems/passenger-6.0.5
     PassengerDefaultRuby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@default/wrappers/ruby
</IfModule>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myserver.com
    DocumentRoot /project/rails_webapp/public
    RailsEnv production
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  <Directory "/project/rails_webapp/public/">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

For rails app:
Installed Webpack, yarn, credentials etc.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue. 
This occurred due to cloning of the EC2 instance. We used latest versions of Ruby, Rails & Passenger. But in Apache config was still pointing to the old passenger version.

So reinstalled passenger module & it fixed it.